# Geo information of photos

Tags: facebook, geolocation, photos

I want geo information (latitude and longitude) associated with Facebook photos. I looked at the documentation and couldn't find it. Does anyone have any idea about the same?

Answer (score 0):

MAybe the information is stored in the EXIF data of the photos?

Comment: No, Facebook clears all EXIF info on upload. (Although I'm sure they store it for themselves...)